# Deploying cloud functions to firebase successful in the CLI but none appear in the dashboard

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been following the codelabs tutorial [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#7) to deploy my first functions to firebase. I've made it to step 8 of the tutorial ("Welcome new users").

The deploy looks successful when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` from within the functions subdirectory:

> Marks-MacBook-Air-3:functions mf$ firebase deploy --only functions
>
> === Deploying to 'friendlychat-21221'...
>
> i  deploying functions Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR"
>   run lint
>
> > functions@ lint /Users/mf/Desktop/friendlychat-web/cloud-functions-start/functions
> >     eslint .
>
> ✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script. i  functions:
>   ensuring necessary APIs are enabled... 
>   ✔  functions: all necessary
>   APIs are enabled 
>   i  functions: preparing functions directory for
>   uploading...
>
> ✔  Deploy complete!

But looking at my firebase dashboard, it doesn't look like they deployed after all:
[image]

I'm not even sure where to begin troubleshooting, since the logs in the cloud functions tab is empty.

Has anyone encountered this before and/or have a good troubleshooting strategy?

Update 1:15 PM Friday 25 May, 2018: This is my index.js file in the functions subdirectory:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// TODO(DEVELOPER): Write the addWelcomeMessages Function here.
// Adds a message that welcomes new users into the chat.
exports.addWelcomeMessages = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {
  console.log('A new user signed in for the first time.');
  const fullName = user.displayName || 'Anonymous';

  // Saves the new welcome message into the database
  // which then displays it in the FriendlyChat clients.
  return admin.database().ref('messages').push({
    name: 'Firebase Bot',
    photoUrl: '/images/firebase-logo.png', // Firebase logo
    text: `${fullName} signed in for the first time! Welcome!`, // Using back-ticks.
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Welcome message written to database.');
  });
});
// TODO(DEVELOPER): Write the blurOffensiveImages Function here.

// TODO(DEVELOPER): Write the sendNotifications Function here.
```

Here are the contents of the functions subdirectory:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are exporting the function you are trying to deploy in your index.js file.

Comment: @fatemefazli I added index.js above. I believe that I am exporting. Can you confirm that the above is what you meant?

Comment: i mean making sure the index.js file containing all your functions are saved on the "functions" folder inside the project folder.

Comment: @fatemefazli gotcha. Yup. Index.js is in there (updated)

Comment: emmm it seems OK, consider that [Deploying functions extremely slow](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/536).

Comment: For troubleshooting help, please contact Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting it to work after changing two things (and I'm not sure which one fixed this issue; perhaps both):

1. run `npm install` from inside the functions directory before you deploy the functions (which should be done in the parent directory).
2. Be aware that when you run `firebase init` and cause an overwrite of your index.js file, that file may just have a commented out 'helloWorld' function...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Firebase list`  to list all the project that you have in firebase under the signed in account and see if the project you are deploying to shows up. In the case where it doesn't show try this:

- `firebase logout && firebase login`
- `firebase list`
- `firebase use <alias_or_project_id>`
- `firebase deploy --only functions` or `firebase deploy --only functions:<function_name>`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can confirm that my project is the current project. No change in behavior, unfortunately.

Comment: In that case I would file a ticket https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting